# What does the term "arbitrary number" mean in math?

Tags: terminology, definition

What does "*arbitrary number*" means in math? I've often seen this vocabulary but I can't find the meaning of it. For example, I'll see phrases like "*arbitrary positive integer*".

Comment: "Arbitrary" basically means "any". So if we say something like "let $n$ be an arbitrary integer", you can think of this as "let $n$ be any integer"

Comment: The way I explain it to my students, for example: "Let $k$ be an arbitrary positive integer. I don't care what it is, it's just a positive integer."

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary definition: based on random choice or personal whim, rather than any reason or system.

That's exactly what it means, even in the context of math.

Answer (score 0):

An arbitrary number is any number. Be it positive or negative.